# my d3 y axis overflow when text become long, how to break word in chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").transition().call(yAxis);
```

how to add a break to every text that is generated on y-axis. I exactly couldn't update the text in the js

Answer (score 1):

You can use the wrap function used [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) to wrap long text in axis labels

```
function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Call like this.

```
svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll(".tick text")
      .call(wrap, x.rangeBand());
```

This is for x-axis, if you need y-axis you need to apply it for y-axis

[image]